# Boolean function in program returns that an entered range is invalid no matter what

Tags: c++, boolean

I am working on a program that determines if there are numbers with repeating digits within a range. The program itself works fine - but one component of it is determining whether or not the user entered range is valid. It is required that I make a boolean function for this called range_is_valid. The two inputs are a and b, if b

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdbool.h>
using namespace std;


//function for finding repeating digits
bool has_repeating_digits(int number){
    bool hasDigit[10] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    int count = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        if (hasDigit[digit]){
            return true; // We already have this digit0
        }
        hasDigit[digit] = true; // Flag the digit we just found
        number /= 10; // Divide by 10, to move onto the next digit
    }
    return false; // If we get here, there is no repeat digit
}  

//function for counting valid numbers
int count_valid_nums(int a, int b, int count){
    int validnums = ((b - a) + 1) - count; //the total range minus the count of invalid nums leaves just valid nums
    return validnums; 
}

//function for determining if inputted range is valid
bool range_is_valid(int a, int b){
    if ((a > b) || (a < 0) || (b < 0) || (a > 10000) || (b > 10000)) {
        return false; //if any of those are true then invalid range
    }
}

int main(){
    //variables
    int a, b, i, count= 0; // a & b inputs, i for iterating

    //entering number range
    cout << "Enter numbers 0 < a <= b <= 10000: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    //Check if the range is valid
    range_is_valid(a,b);
    if (range_is_valid(a, b) == false){
        cout << "The range is invalid" << endl;
    }

    //making a vector to contain numbers between a and b
    vector<int> listofnums((b-a)+1); 
    int initialvalue = a;
    while (i <= (b-a)) {  
        listofnums[i] = initialvalue;                                 


        //call the has repeating digits function
        has_repeating_digits(listofnums[i]);
        if (has_repeating_digits(listofnums[i])){ //counting how many numbers in vector have repeat digits
            count++;
        }   
        initialvalue++; 
        i++;

    }

    //call the count valid numbers function
    cout << "There are " << count_valid_nums (a, b, count) << " valid numbers between " << a << " and " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to `return true;` when the condition is not met.

Comment: do i need to change it to if range_is_valid == true in my if statement too? I just changed it in the function itself and it's still telling me that a valid range (a = 8 and b = 13) is invalid @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @idclev463035818 When I enter a range that should be valid, so no negative numbers, a is less than b, and nothing is greater than 10000, it still outputs that my entered range is invalid

Comment: `range_is_valid` NEVER return `true` as written here...or maybe it does. You never explicitly `return true` anywhere in the function.

Comment: 101 reasons to look at your compiler messages:   #87  you find missing return statements

Comment: `if (!range_is_valid(a, b)) { cout << "The range is invalid" << endl; }` should work if you fixed the function properly. Also, you can simplify the entire function to: `return ((a < b) && (a > 0) && (b < 10000));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have this

```
if (condition) return true;
else return false;
```

You can as well write

```
return condition;
```

In `range_is_valid` you have

```
if (condition) return false;
// missing return !!!!
```

which returns nothing when `condition == false`. You can write it as

```
return !(condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. It seems that the both numbers shall be positive and not greater than 10000.

The function can look for example the following way

```
bool range_is_valid(int a, int b)
{
    return a <= b && a > 0 && b <= 10'000; 
}
```

However it is not a good approach because the function uses a magic number `10000`.

It is better to pass such a number as an argument of the function.

Taking this in account the function can look the following wayg

```
#include <utility>

//...

bool range_is_valid( const std::pair<int, int> &data, const std::pair<int, int> &range )
{
    return data.first <= data.second && 
           data.first > range.first  &&
           data.second <= range.second;   
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

bool range_is_valid( const std::pair<int, int> &data, const std::pair<int, int> &range )
{
    return data.first <= data.second && 
           data.first > range.first  &&
           data.second <= range.second;   
}

int main() 
{
    const std::pair<int, int> range( 0, 10'000 );

    int a, b;

    size_t attempts = 3;

    while ( attempts-- != 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter numbers " << range.first << 
                     " < a <= b <= " << range.second << '\n';

        std::cin >> a >> b;

        std::cout << std::boolalpha << range_is_valid( { a, b }, range ) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
Enter numbers 0 < a <= b <= 10000
0 10000
false
Enter numbers 0 < a <= b <= 10000
1 10001
false
Enter numbers 0 < a <= b <= 10000
1 10000
true
```

Always try to write a more generic function.

Pay attention to that this declaration

```
bool hasDigit[10] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
```

looks silly.

You could just write

```
bool hasDigit[10] = {};
```

or

```
bool hasDigit[10] = { false };
```